# Find the area of the square $OABC$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

[image]

Find the area of the square $OABC$.

Comment: I found the quadratic equation

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- What can you say about the coordinate $B$ based on property of a square?
- Find the equation of the quadratic equation.
- use the two properties above and solve a simultaneous equation to recover coordinate of $B$.